# C2678 binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Card' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, c++11, find

I am getting the above error caused by the tie break function

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Hand{
private:
std::vector<Card> cards;
public:
  PokerHand(Card c1, Card c2) {
      cards.push_back(c1);
      cards.push_back(c2);
      cards.push_back(c3);
      cards.push_back(c4);
      cards.push_back(c5);
  }
bool breakTie(const PokerHand& other) const{
    std::vector<Card> temp1 = { cards };
    std::vector<Card> temp2 = { other.getCards()};
    return std::find(temp1.begin(), temp1.end(), 2) <    std::find(temp2.begin(), temp2.end(), 2)
}
std::vector<Card> getCards(){
    return cards;
}
};

class Card{
private:
    int value;
public:
    bool operator ==(const Card& right)const {
        return (this->value == right.getValue());
    }
    int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    Card(int value){
        this->value=value;
    }
};

int main(){
    Card a(4);
    Card b(5);
    Hand hand(a,b);
    hand.breakTie();
    return 0;
}
```

From what i understand the error means that i am trying to change a const variable. What I don't understand is how I am changing a const variable?

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: *I believe the line that is causing the error is* -- What line did the compiler say the error occurs?  Also, what is `determineHand`?  Is that a non-const function?  Is it even a member function?  Please post a [mcve], as any C++ compilation error can be duplicated with just a small amount of code.

Comment: I recognize that normally you would require less code. It did say that line, but i had more because I was not sure if there could be more errors in other lines. I will edit my source to include only the basics.

Comment: No, edit your source to start [like this](https://rextester.com/TFJGY20263).  This compiles with no errors.  Add to (or remove from) that simple example, and when you get the error, post *exactly* and everything contained in your code, including headers.

Comment: Look at the FIRST line with an error.  Once the code is wrong, the later errors can be misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `find` on a vector of `Card`s with the integer `2`.  You are getting that error because `2` is not a `Card`, nor is there any constructor for `Card` that takes one integer parameter that can be used (either there is none, or the one that exists is marked `explicit`).

You need to clarify (to the compiler) what it is your looking for.  What is `Card` 2?

Comment: so i should pass it a card object?

Comment: @matthew12345 A card is what is stored in your vector, so that is what you should be looking for.